# ZFS: 3 whole disks + partition vs 4 whole disks

Tags: linux, debian, zfs

While the title is ambiguous, I couldn't find an appropriate one. New to `ZFS`.

I have 1 proxmox server at SoYouStart for testing purposes. The server has 4x2TB HDD (SoftRAID), and the partition table I can set is limited: I must have 3 partitions minimum, `/`, `swap` and `/var/lib/vz`. I can choose RAID 0, 1, 5, 10 or no RAID, and the partition types are `ext3`, `ext4` or `xfs`.

What I have done so far is installing Proxmox on the 1st disk with no raid, and created a `Raidz1` on the 3 others. Now I have 6TB available on ZFS (which is great) and 1.76TB on the first disk, and I would like to migrate entirely on ZFS.

Now I wonder, is it better to have 3 whole disks on ZFS + a big partition on the 1st disk (leaving proxmox entirely on `ext4`) or is it better to migrate the boot partition to the existing ZFS pool and add the 4th disk to the pool afterward? Is there a downside of booting from a zpool, or should I absolutely go for it if I can manage the migration?

As a precision, SyS team told me their KVM/IP won't allow me to boot an ISO and do the install myself.

Comment: For So you Start only the SYS-LE-* servers have an IPMI which allows you to do the OS installation yourself. These are not normally sold, but only at certain times of the year, and only announced on the OVH mailing list. If you want such a server, get on this mailing list and pick one the next time they are offered.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for the input, one of my servers is indeed a SYS-LE-*, but not the others (I was too late to take the second one)